# Samsung tablet won't connect to WiFi or blue tooth

Tags: samsung, tablet

Model SM-T230NU
Android 4.4.2

Refuses to connect to WiFi or blue tooth.
The both switches stay off, all greyed out in colour....

Please help ...

Thanks in advance

Eli

Comment: Please add more details in the question to get a detailed solution. Screenshot would help. most recent changes you performed on the device? Rooted? Custom Rom? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far ?

Comment: I used my tablet for about 4months, before i encountered this problem. I tried reseting my tablet to factory settings but that didn't help. I did  out of the orginary to it other than download Google play apps.

Comment: Problem - when I try to turn on WiFi or blue tooth the switches stay in turned off and gray.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your question is completely vague, I'm taking a total guess:

Turn `Airplane Mode` off.

[image]